# Is it possible to generate this result (list to matrix layout) by using Excel formulae only?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula, excel-2010, pivot-table

I have two columns of data:

```
F1 | A
F1 | B
F2 | C
F3 | D
F3 | E
F2 | F
F3 | G
```

By using Excel formulae, is it possible to generate the following result?:

```
F1 | A | B
F2 | C | F
F3 | D | E | G
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, various ways but none particularly easy. One way is to add labels and use a PivotTable (assuming that counts within "excel forumulas") with your left-hand column for Row Labels, your right-hand column for Column Labels and for Σ Values (as Count of). Then copy your left-hand PT column, paste it elsewhere and next to the top of it on the right insert a formula such as `=IF(E3=1,E$2,x)`. Copy the formula across and down to suit, then select the resulting formula array and Go To Special, Formulas, Errors. Right-click on one of the selected cells and Delete... with Shift cells left.

Comment: It's not very easy indeed, but it works. If no better answer comes out, I'll choose this.Thank you, @pnuts

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve such thing is using filters:

Add headline to each column, mark the whole table (in your case, the two columns with their new headlines), and then click the right mouse button to open a menu.
Then choose Filter -> Filter by selected cell value.
If you want them together, you can just duplicate you table, and filter each table by separate value!

Another option, is to sort the array (again - right click menu -> sort).
Sort it according to the first column - and you have the separation you want between the values.
Now you can just use functions like offset and index (and maybe also if condition) to write a complicated formula.

The best way to write the values in different columns is to use Visual Basic Application (try to play with Macros first).